# Cannot build databricks/spark-sql-perf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, databricks, benchmarking

I'm trying to benchmark Databricks using the repo [databricks/spark-sql-perf](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sql-perf). Anyone who have experienced building and running spark-sql-perf successfully? Would really appreciate some help. I'm having issues building the project, and received the following output from sbt:

```
/Users/philipsalqvist/Documents/Utbildning/comp-sc/master-thesis/benchmark/spark-sql perf/build.sbt:94: error: not found: value reapply
    reapply(newSettings, st)
    ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.checkError(Eval.scala:384)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:183)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:152)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalDefinitions(Eval.scala:122)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDefinitions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:271)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:109)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:712)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:717)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:716)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:716)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:723)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:723)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:723)
    at sbt.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:734)
    at sbt.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:545)
    at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:574)
    at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:442)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:446)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:281)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:334)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:289)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:285)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:276)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:130)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:36)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:481)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:475)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:58)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    [error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
    [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Tried using different versions of sbt and scala, no success so far.